# Manifest queries' package names defined in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is there a way to set the AndroidManifest.xml queries' package names in the app's build.gradle file? I have different package names for development and production builds. I don't want to list both development and production packages in the same list, but wanted to list the package names depending on the app's flavor.

It seems that can be used neither the string resources nor the manifest placeholders to define the `queries` packages.

I'd like to do something like this, by using string resources:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="@string/package_1" />
    <package android:name="@string/package_2" />
</queries>
```

or, by using manifest placeholders,

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="${package_1}" />
    <package android:name="${package_2}" />
</queries>
```

but it seems the only way to define package names is to write them explicitly.